# Выбор результатов от нескольких переменных

Tags: алгоритм

Не судите строго, не могу никак организовать алгоритм, есть девять переменных которые возвращают одно из трех значение, например, (ок, error, пустую строку) если одна из девяти переменных возвращает error или пустую строку, то пропустить эту переменную и проверять дальше, в конце сделать действие (например архивацию). Пробовал и через вложеный if и через switch.

Comment: Не понятно мне .з.

Comment: Делайте через for и if.

Comment: Стало проще когда обьединили результат error и постую строку в servererror

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял, что под возвратом переменной значения, подразумевается чтение значения переменной.

Девять это много.

В программировании есть понятия: Одно, Два и Много. Если Много, то надо обобщать.

Короче, используйте не девять переменных, а один массив с девятью элементами.